# Can the powersets of two different cardinals be of the same cardinality?

Tags: set-theory

Is the following statement consistent with ZF (obviously, this is not true in ZFC)?

> There are cardinals $\kappa, \lambda$ such that $\kappa \neq \lambda$ and $2^\kappa = 2^\lambda$.

Comment: Surely this type of thing has been asked multiple times at MO? One instance is here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82769/is-it-consistent-with-zfc-that-for-all-ordinals-alpha-beta-omega-it-hold/82782#82782 (which asks for a stronger statement).

Comment: I am sorry, I failed to find the answer through searching. The moderators can delete my question.

Comment: It's okay to keep the question. This one should be easy for others to find in future searches, esp. since the title is in plain English.

Comment: According to MO users, that different cardinals should not have power sets of the same size is the most reasonable-sounding statement which is independent of ZFC (with 224 votes as of right now). See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1924/what-are-some-reasonable-sounding-statements-that-are-independent-of-zfc/#6594).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, even with ZFC. In Cohen's model, where the continuum hypothesis fails, he gets ZFC plus $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$. This statement is known as [Luzin's hypothesis](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Luzin_hypothesis), an alternative to CH.

More generally, the situation for regular cardinals is described by [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem), which says that if ZFC plus the GCH holds, then for any function $E:\kappa\mapsto E(\kappa)$ on the regular cardinals satisfying the properties that $\kappa\leq\lambda\to E(\kappa)\leq E(\lambda)$ and $\kappa<\operatorname{cof}(E(\kappa))$, then there is a forcing extension in which $2^\kappa=E(\kappa)$.

In particular, one can easily make functions $E$ that will thereby ensure ZFC plus many instances of $2^\kappa=2^\lambda$.